# Selectivizr :first-of-type and nth-of-type not working in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, mootools, pseudo-class, selectivizr

I'm starting a new project, and since it won't use much javascript, I decided to switch from Jquery to Mootools only because of the range of pseudo-class selectors it will let me use.

Problem is, it still won't work!

In IE8, I can't get firt-of-type or nth-of-type(2) to properly work!

It works perfectly in Chrome/FF/IE9.

I have emptied the cache I don't know how many times.

Also, I know that Selectivizr is loaded since :first-child actually works in IE8.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: mootools will just allow you javascript selectors - i.e. to select elements from dom. it's not going to extend the selectors Slick supports to the dom for general CSS use.

Comment: Did you read the documentation about Selectivizr at all?  Do you know what it is?

Comment: Here are some excerpts: 
"selectivizr is a JavaScript utility that emulates CSS3 pseudo-classes and attribute selectors in Internet Explorer 6-8. Simply include the script in your pages and selectivizr will do the rest."

"Just include this script in your page's <head> tag. If you're not already using a JavaScript library, you'll need to choose one from the table below."

This is why you need either Mootools or Jquery, to allow it to work, and it does for certain things, but not everything mentioned in the table listing the different pseudo-classes it's supposed to let you use.

Comment: It IS working; but not in it's entirety.  There are documented bugs on the web, but none concerning my own issue...

Comment: can you post some relevant HTML/ CSS/ mooTools code that is supposedly not working? I am confident this is not a mootools issue as I have tons of code that uses pseudo-class selectors perfectly.

Comment: Check out this fiddle in IE7 or IE8 (I think IE6 would even work) http://jsfiddle.net/qtu5E/1/ you may want to check out your syntax in the selector.

Comment: yes. @Neonjack selectivizer is meant to give you CSS3 selectors in your standard CSS and will be powered by mootools. mootools supports these selectors just fine. hence your issue is with selectivizr or your css - it needs to be in a file via a `<link>` tag and on the same domain. inline styles won't work

Comment: What does all of this has to do with selectivizr?  I appreciate the fact that you're taking your time to answer me, but do you know anything about selectivizr?  You keep mentioning mootools and javascript, but it's totally not what I'm having trouble with...

Comment: OK, to be PERFECTLY clear, have a look here: 
http://mehdi.ca/tests/test.html

Comment: to be perfectly blunt, you need to isolate your case so it does not rely on real time less parsing that also messes the same css source. if it does not work still - given that the mootools slick selector supports it - you need to edit the mapping. docs state compat with 1.3 and it's now 1.4.5 but support for these selectors has been working since 1.3 so there should not be any breaking changes.

Comment: `:first-child` is not CSS3; it working in IE8 has nothing to do with Selectivizr.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the <=ie8 browser css engines do not support the child condition.

There are some good jquery addons that can help youout.

Comment: I know that <=ie8 won't support pseudo-classes, thus the use of the selectivizr script, check the compatibility table:
http://selectivizr.com/

Comment: And using selectivizr with jquery has severe limitations; it's why I switched to mootools.

But it's all in my first question.